# How to resolve ':ios:copyNatives FAILED'. Could not find property 'natives' on configuration container

Tags: gradle, libgdx, robovm

I am using libgdx 1.7.0 and Robovm version 1.8.0 and robovm gradle version 1.8.0

I have made my run configuration for iOS as described in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

When I attempted to run iOS configuration, I have got this gradle exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/senthilkumark/Documents/Projects/nzfour/ios/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios:copyNatives'.
> Could not find property 'natives' on configuration container.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

latest robovm does not need ios:CopyNatives task.

I have commented the following lines

```
/ Extracts native libs (*.a) from the native-ios.jar and places them
// under build/libs/ios/.
//task copyNatives << {
//  file("build/libs/ios/").mkdirs();
//  configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
//    def outputDir = null
//    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-ios.jar")) outputDir = file("build/libs/ios")
//    if (outputDir != null) {
//      copy {
//        from zipTree(jar)
//        into outputDir
//        include "*.a"
//      }
//    }
//  }
//}
```

and this one too.

```
//updateRoboVMXML.dependsOn copyNatives
```

It solved my issue.